# Migrating from Git to TFVC in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops

I have an ADO project that was incorrectly setup to use Git as it's source control provider. We need to switch it to TFVC. We don't have any code in their yet, just a lot of PBIs. I don't see a way to change this in the project options. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no code, just add a TFVC repository to the project and start using it. Work items are completely unrelated. Projects don't use Git or TFVC, they use Git *and* TFVC. You can have one TFVC repo per project and an essentially unlimited number of Git repos, both at the same time.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @jessehouwing thats wrong. you can create a tfvc-repo in a project that has been set up to use git. go to project settings -> repositories -> create -> select repository type as tfvc. note that you can only have one tfvc-repo in a project

Comment: @jessehouwing That hasn't been true for years.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the single TFVC repository for project since it is on root level by design, you may navigate your ***organization setting*** with assume enough permission you have (e.g PCA) , and you can create the TFVC repo, and assign the permission to project administrators member group at project level.

migrating to TFVC once the workspace is created, you can use the operation cli to check/in/out/commit on the items.